# Got a java.lang.IllegalArgumentException when sending a Java object by the dynamic TCP/IP integration flow?

Tags: java, spring, spring-integration, spring-integration-ip

Gary Russell helped me some time ago with the following 'DynamicTcpServer' flow (see [Building a TCP/IP server with SI's dynamic flow registration](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62867670/how-to-configure-spring-integration-adapters-of-a-merely-connecting-client-and-a)) having now a message service injected which gets the message to send as soon as a client connects:

```
public class DynamicTcpServer implements TcpServer {

    @Autowired
    private IntegrationFlowContext flowContext;

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext appContext;

    private final Map<String, IntegrationFlowRegistration> registrations = new HashMap<>();

    private final Map<String, String> clients = new ConcurrentHashMap<>();

    private final Map<String, TcpServerSpec> sockets;

    private final MessageService messenger;

    @Autowired
    public DynamicTcpServer(MessageService messenger, Map<String, TcpServerSpec> sockets) {
        this.messenger = messenger;
        this.sockets = sockets;
    }

    @Override
    public void start(String context) {
        start(context, sockets.get(context).getPort());
    }

    @Override
    public void start(String context, int port) {
        if (this.registrations.containsKey(context)) {
            /* already running */
        }
        else {
            TcpServerConnectionFactorySpec server = Tcp.netServer(port).id(context).serializer(TcpCodecs.lf());
            server.get().registerListener(msg -> false); // dummy listener so the accept thread doesn't exit
            IntegrationFlow flow = f -> f.handle(Tcp.outboundAdapter(server));
            this.registrations.put(context, flowContext.registration(flow).register());
        }
    }

    @Override
    public Set<String> running() {
        return registrations.keySet();
    }

    @Override
    public void stop(String context) {
        IntegrationFlowRegistration registration = this.registrations.remove(context);
        if (registration != null) {
            registration.destroy();
        }
    }

    @EventListener
    public void connect(TcpConnectionOpenEvent event) {
        String connectionId = event.getConnectionId();
        this.clients.put(connectionId, event.getConnectionFactoryName());
    }

    @EventListener
    public void closed(TcpConnectionCloseEvent event) {
        this.clients.remove(event.getConnectionId());
    }

    @EventListener
    public void listening(TcpConnectionServerListeningEvent event) {
    }

    @Scheduled(
            fixedDelayString = "${com.harry.potter.scheduler.fixed-delay}",
            initialDelayString = "${com.harry.potter.scheduler.initial-delay}"
    )
    public void sender() {
        this.clients.forEach((connectId, context) -> {
            IntegrationFlowRegistration register = registrations.get(context);
            if (register != null) {
                try {
                    while (true) {
                        List<ServerMessage> msgs = messenger.getMessagesToSend(sockets.get(context));
                        msgs.stream().forEach(msg -> 
                                register.getMessagingTemplate().send(
                                        MessageBuilder.withPayload(msg)
                                                .setHeader(IpHeaders.CONNECTION_ID, connectId).build()));       
                    }
                }
                catch (NoMessageToSendException nm) {
                    appContext.getBean(context, TcpNetServerConnectionFactory.class)
                            .closeConnection(connectId);    
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

The message service returns a Java object 'com.harry.potter.entity.ServerMessage' to be sent.
So I assume I have to add some other kind of converter at '.serializer(TcpCodecs.lf())' because I got an exception saying:

```
2022-04-17 04:00:45.729 DEBUG [] --- [pool-283-thread-1]  c.l.c.c.cas.service.DynamicTcpServer     : sender: send 1 messages to potter1
2022-04-17 04:00:45.738 DEBUG [] --- [pool-283-thread-1]  c.l.c.c.c.service.DynamicTcpServer     : closed event=TcpConnectionCloseEvent [source=TcpNetConnection:harry.potter.de:56746:17584:76adefe0-0881-4e4b-be2b-0ced47f950ae], [factory=potter1, connectionId=harry.potter.de:56746:17584:76adefe0-0881-4e4b-be2b-0ced47f950ae] **CLOSED**
2022-04-17 04:00:45.740 ERROR [] --- [pool-283-thread-1]  o.s.i.ip.tcp.TcpSendingMessageHandler    : Error sending message

org.springframework.messaging.MessagingException: Send Failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: When using a byte array serializer, the socket mapper expects either a byte array or String payload, but received: class com.harry.potter.entity.ServerMessage
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection.send(TcpNetConnection.java:118)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpSendingMessageHandler.handleMessageAsServer(TcpSendingMessageHandler.java:119)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.TcpSendingMessageHandler.handleMessageInternal(TcpSendingMessageHandler.java:103)
    at org.springframework.integration.handler.AbstractMessageHandler.handleMessage(AbstractMessageHandler.java:62)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.AbstractDispatcher.tryOptimizedDispatch(AbstractDispatcher.java:115)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.doDispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:133)
    at org.springframework.integration.dispatcher.UnicastingDispatcher.dispatch(UnicastingDispatcher.java:106)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractSubscribableChannel.doSend(AbstractSubscribableChannel.java:72)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:570)
    at org.springframework.integration.channel.AbstractMessageChannel.send(AbstractMessageChannel.java:520)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:187)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:166)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.GenericMessagingTemplate.doSend(GenericMessagingTemplate.java:47)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:109)
    at org.springframework.messaging.core.AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.send(AbstractMessageSendingTemplate.java:99)
    at com.harry.potter.service.DynamicTcpServer.lambda$sender$2(DynamicTcpServer.java:125)
    at com.harry.potter.service.DynamicTcpServer$$Lambda$40600/0x000000006f511b08.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.ArrayList$ArrayListSpliterator.forEachRemaining(ArrayList.java:1625)
    at java.base/java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$Head.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:762)
    at com.harry.potter.service.DynamicTcpServer.lambda$sender$3(DynamicTcpServer.java:124)
    at com.harry.potter.service.DynamicTcpServer$$Lambda$40552/0x000000003344f3b0.accept(Unknown Source)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ConcurrentHashMap.forEach(ConcurrentHashMap.java:1603)
    at com.harry.potter.service.DynamicTcpServer.sender(DynamicTcpServer.java:115)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
    at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.ScheduledMethodRunnable.run(ScheduledMethodRunnable.java:84)
    at org.springframework.scheduling.support.DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.run(DelegatingErrorHandlingRunnable.java:54)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Executors.java:539)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.runAndReset(FutureTask.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor$ScheduledFutureTask.run(ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.java:305)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1136)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:635)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:884)
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: When using a byte array serializer, the socket mapper expects either a byte array or String payload, but received: class com.harry.potter.entity.ServerMessage
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpMessageMapper.getPayloadAsBytes(TcpMessageMapper.java:277)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpMessageMapper.fromMessage(TcpMessageMapper.java:252)
    at org.springframework.integration.ip.tcp.connection.TcpNetConnection.send(TcpNetConnection.java:111)
    ... 34 common frames omitted
```

Which converter (serializer) do I have to use and how to plug it in my DynamicTcpServer exactly?

**EDIT 1**

The message service `messenger` returns a Java object 'com.harry.potter.entity.ServerMessage' to be sent. The `ServerMessage` contains an int field holding the message length and a String field holding the message text:

```
public class ServerMessage implements Serializable {
    private static final long serialVersionUID = -1L;

    private int len;
    private String message;

    /* getters & setters */
}
```

I am trying to migrate from a C/C++ function which writes the C Struct

```
struct C_MSG
{
    int len;                        /* Length field */
    char text[MAX_MSG_LEN];         /* Data field   */
} c_msg;
```

to a consumer using the C Socket library `send` function writing a given number of bytes (length of text + 4) from the given memory address to the given TCP/IP socket.

I am looking for a Transformer to prepare the same binary content for the message consumer. Otherwise the consumer will not be able to cope with the message.

Following the comments and looking at the `GenericTransformer<S, T>` the transformation could be done in a single Lambda expression. The source of the transformation would be an object of the ServerMessage? The result should be an array of Bytes using Spring's utility:

```
.transform(s -> SerializationUtils.serialize(s))
```

Will the Lambda expression be that one? Perhaps do I need a custom Transformer - to have more control over the serializing process in case my consumer expects Intel resp. Motorola byte order - with implementing a specific interface? Which one? Perhaps there is a much easier solution?

Comment: What part of "When using a byte array serializer, the socket mapper expects either a byte array or String payload, but received: class `com.harry.potter.entity.ServerMessage`" didn't you understand?

Comment: You assume correctly. You can only send a byte array, and it is the responsibility of the server and client to convert the object to a byte array and send/receive the byte array in a way that they both understand. Typically this would be done with some easy to work with format like JSON which contains the raw data and is easy to convert to and from a byte array, rather than your custom ServerMessage object.

Comment: @sorifiend According to the error message you can also send a `String`.

Comment: I did understand. But the question aimed to what and where to plug-in the correct converter/transformer.

Comment: @sorifiend: Why do use a comment to answer the question?

Comment: @user207421: Your About is "Most of my posts contain facts that may upset people who are firmly convinced of the opposite. This is not my problem."
This post didn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to think about `.transform()` before that `.handle(Tcp.outboundAdapter(server));` to convert your `ServerMessage` to `byte[]` or `String`. That's what is expected in the `TcpMessageMapper` by default.

Of course I could recommend you to look into the `mapper(TcpMessageMapper mapper)` option of the `Tcp.netServer()` and its `bytesMessageMapper` property, but the outcome would be just the same.

Comment: Thank you, Artem! What your are saying is to put:
`IntegrationFlow flow = f -> f.transform().handle(Tcp.outboundAdapter(server));`?
And the flow intuitively knows to convert my object into an Array of Bytes?

Comment: That’s not true. It is your project responsibility to implement “to bytes array conversion”. We just cannot know what is your strategy to apply for such a transformation. But framework provides for you a hook where you can insert that logic. And in my opinion the `transform()` is the best place to put that logic in.

Comment: Thanks Artem! Would you mind being a bit more specific? In the documentation I found in the Transformers section an Object-to-String transformer. I think I need such a kind. There is described to configuer as `<int:object-to-string-transformer input-channel="in" output-channel="out"/>`. But how do I make this with DSL? And where?

Comment: You don't need that factory. See this Java DSL method: `public <S, T> B transform(GenericTransformer<S, T> genericTransformer) {` which is just lambda to accept your `ServerMessage` and you do the logic to convert it to `byte[]`. Again: we just don't know what is your strategy  and how you are going to covert that  `ServerMessage`  to `byte[]`. The `ObjectToStringTransformer` just won't help you here because in the end it is going to be a plain  `ServerMessage.toString()`.

Comment: Thanks Artem! Please take a look at my EDIT 1: I tried to explain what transformation is required. Please advice!

Comment: I don't remember already C++ to be sure that your `struct` representation in Java is correct. But that `ServerMessage` definitely cannot be a `Serializable` if your other side is not a Java or it does not have this `ServerMessage` in its classpath. Also it is not clear why would one have a `len` property when `String` in Java has it own `length` property. I believe the question about proper conversion to `byte[]`  should be move to its own SO thread involving already some C++ community members. Perhaps something like `ServerMessage.getMessage().getBytes()` is enough for you...

Comment: Thanks Artem! Of course you can serialize on the Java side and look whatever the legacy system on the other side is about to read. You need to encure that the int lenght comes as an 4 byte array before the message character/byte array (because that is the way my legacy receiver expects a message). But you are right, Java serializing maybe does not happen to produce the byte array the receiver expects. Thatswhy my question aimed to have an custom transformer with which to control the byte array result.

Comment: See `ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer` for this kind of interaction. You still need to convert your string to its `byte[]`. That `ByteArrayLengthHeaderSerializer` will calculate the length and populate respective header into the TCP/IP package. See more info in docs: https://docs.spring.io/spring-integration/docs/current/reference/html/ip.html#tcp-codecs